# JWT auth in lumen

Tags: laravel-5

I complete Login With Token Generate Like This

"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0L2x1bWVuL2F1dGgvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NzUwNjAwMzMsImV4cCI6MTQ3NTA2MzYzMywibmJmIjoxNDc1MDYwMDMzLCJqdGkiOiIwOTFjYWNhZGRlODQ1NjNhMzc4M2JkM2EwNDdkZmM3YSIsInN1YiI6M30.VjXTSkzrmzTQSTZvp3VxlWacL8VHyM8XBUa5db8GOOI"

But When i Run api with jwt.auth middleware it give response

{
  "message": "Token not provided"
}

How  I can solve it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are providing the token in the headers properly as specified in the [JWT documentation](https://jwt.io/introduction/#how-do-json-web-tokens-work-)?

You need to send the `Authorization` header followed by `Bearer TOKEN`.

So the final result in your case would be:

`Authorization` : `Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0L2x1bWVuL2F1dGgvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NzUwNjAwMzMsImV4cCI6MTQ3NTA2MzYzMywibmJmIjoxNDc1MDYwMDMzLCJqdGkiOiIwOTFjYWNhZGRlODQ1NjNhMzc4M2JkM2EwNDdkZmM3YSIsInN1YiI6M30.VjXTSkzrmzTQSTZvp3VxlWacL8VHyM8XBUa5db8GOOI`